# What is the origin of the phrase "cut and dried"?

Tags: etymology, idioms

How did the phrase "cut and dry" come to mean clearly decided or settled in advance? Sometimes referenced as "cut and dried". Also used when when referring to something that is ordinary.

If something is "cut and dry", it is said to be completed without debate, question, or argument.

Example: The rule about running near the pool was cut and dry, but the boy broke the rule and ran anyway.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The standard expression is *cut and dried*, though usages such as *That's pretty cut and dry* have started to appear more in recent decades, as [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pretty%20cut%20and%20dried%2Cpretty%20cut%20and%20dry&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpretty%20cut%20and%20dried%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpretty%20cut%20and%20dry%3B%2Cc0) shows.

It's a metaphoric reference to grass/hay/herbs/etc. being cut, dried, and thus ready for sale/use (nothing more needs to be done). By extension it comes to mean no more discussion needs to take place. By further extension, no decision or thought is required at all (the *ordinary* default suffices).

OP's example isn't a very appropriate one. Most people would say the rule was *clear-cut* (overt, explicit, unambiguous), not *cut and dried* (fully decided upon, finalised, settled).

Comment: I've actually heard people use "that's pretty cut and dry" in spoken English. Of course, spoken English isn't always correct English.

Comment: @simchona: You're right. Notwithstanding my comment to PPL's Answer, I'll amend mine to reflect this usage.

Comment: "Cut and dry" is attested long before the 20th century. [Swift used it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grisette_(person)#Jonathan_Swift)! (He was filling out a rhyme though.) I see why you included "pretty," but I think it also produces skewed results.

Comment: @simchona: And of course, there's the whole question of whether there *is* such a thing as "correct English." :-)

Comment: From my experience, I think it's used to mean clear-cut more often than the metaphor. I think the OP's example is a common usage.

Comment: @Vimes: "clear-cut" ***is*** the metaphoric sense! The *literal* meaning is how you prepare and store cooking herbs, etc. But note that figurative "cut & dried" has that sense of ***already decided, no further debate allowed***, which isn't necessarily present in "clear-cut" (no ambiguity). And *that's* why OP's usage isn't very appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

The OED describes this usage as:

> ***cut and dried*** (also ***cut and dry***): originally referring to herbs in the herbalists' shops, as contrasted with growing herbs; hence, *fig.* ready-made and void of freshness and spontaneity; also, ready shaped according to *a priori* formal notions. (Usually of language, ideas, schemes or the like.)

(I think FumbleFingers’ description captures the current usage slightly better, though: fully settled, ready for use.)

The OED’s citations for *cut and dried* go back to 1710, and for *…dry* to 1730.  [Google Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com) shows that *…dried* has been dominant at least for the last couple of centuries, although *…dry* has remained a consistent minority usage:

[image: Google Ngrams: "cut and dried" vs. "cut and dry"]

Comment: Very few of the (already relatively uncommon) usages of cut and dry reported by NGram are figurative in any sense. They're mostly just the straight literal meaning. I do accept figurative *cut and dry* occurs, but it's a *very* "minority" usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: in recent usage, that’s a good point (out of the top 20 Google books examples since 1954 for *cut and dry*, I count 8 literal, 8 figurative, 4 unclear, as opposed to 4/15/1 for *cut and dried*).  In earlier usage, though, it seems to go the other way — with *…dry* more consistently figurative — although the sample size then is much smaller, so it’s not clear how meaningful that is.